# Python for loop - skip to last element

Tags: python, for-loop

How do we skip to the last element in python?

***ITS CLEAR NOW!!!!!!!!!!!!***

So for example i have a list

```
foo = ['hello', 'world','how']
```

And, I have this loop

```
for i in foo:
    ----------Codes to skip to last element.--------
```

therefore, variable 'i' becomes the last element in foo, which is 'how'.

```
    if i == 'how':
       print 'success!'
```

And yes, i was wondering if there is any method to do so in a for loop, not outside.

The closest I have found is this:

[Python skipping last element in while iterating a list using for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757474/python-skipping-last-element-in-while-iterating-a-list-using-for-loop)

Please add in the explanation for your answers on how it works.

Edit: Also, if it's not possible, please explain why(optional).

Comment: if you what to skip to the last element, then why you use a `for` loop? why not directyly do something with `foo[-1]`

Comment: @Ever I just want to learn even more methods!!!

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to run on the entire list:

```
foo = ['hello', 'world','how']

for i in foo[:-1]:
    ........
```

You can also identify if it's the last by doing:

```
foo = ['hello', 'world','how']

for i in foo:
    if i == foo[-1]:
        print "I'm the last.."
```

For more information about list you can refer [Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

And you have a very good tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm)

Comment: No, but is it possible in the for-loop?

Comment: I mean inside the loop, not on the loop, replacing my commented lines in the code given in the question.

Comment: I want the variable i to skip to the last character IN THE LOOP.

Comment: @leonneo there are no characters since you are iterating items of a list! please try to edit your question and give some example so it will be easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Another method to skip the last element

```
>>> for index, item in enumerate(foo):
        if index==(len(foo)-1):
            # last element 
        else:
            # Do something
```

Comment: Why enumerate? Can you explain?

Comment: enumerate will make certain loops a bit clearer. you will get index of the item along with the item in the sequence.As you need to skip the last element I have taken index and compared it with the len of list to skip the last

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you want to check whether you've reached the end of the cycle without *break* ing out of it. Python has beautiful *for...else* and *while..else* constructs for that. 
The else clause is used when the cycle completes without breaking out
So that the skeleton for your code:

```
for word in foo:
   ... you may break out
else:
    print success
```

Simple and elegant (and more efficient too)

**EDIT:**
OK, now I get what you want. You may use slicing - as it was suggested, but *islice* of *itertools* will do the job better:

```
from itertools import islice:
for word in islice(foo, len(foo)-1):
```

Comment: What breakout? What do you mean?

Comment: In a loop, you may put code _if something: break_ . The meaning is that if condition _something_ evaluates to true, your loop will be interrupted immediately.

Comment: That's for everyone to refer to only. I am making sure they can add all they want. Also, you can help edit, because it is unclear from the comments

Answer (score 0):

You can skip any statement either in last or middle.

```
foo = ['hello', 'world','how']

for i in foo:
    if i == "how" or i == "hello":
        continue
    print(i)
```